# How can I link to a specific windows 10 control panel setting

Tags: windows-10

I want to take a use to a specific setting when they click a link in my app.

#### Background

When I search for a setting in the start menu a result will link to a specific line in the windows 10 settings.

[image: Windows search result]

Clicking the result will link to a specific position on a windows setting page. Is it possible to extract or link to these results without searching them first?

Comment: Try this: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-desktop-shortcuts-specific-settings-windows-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@wysiwyg appears to be correct. The link in the comment links to an article that links [here](https://winaero.com/how-to-open-various-settings-pages-directly-in-windows-10/).*

It describes how to create a shortcut and set the link to `ms-settings:[link]`. Here's some examples:

- ms-settings:batterysaver
- ms-settings:batterysaver-settings
- ms-settings:easeofaccess-magnifier
- ms-settings:privacy-feedback
- ms-settings:privacy-location
- ms-settings:privacy-webcam
- ms-settings:network-cellular
- ms-settings:network-dialup
- ms-settings:network-directaccess
- ms-settings:network-ethernet
- ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot
- ms-settings:network-wifi
- ms-settings:themes
- ms-settings:privacy